# unable to replace digits with space on text preprocessing

Tags: python, nlp

Iam trying to pre-process text as a part of NLP.I am new to it.I am not getting why i am unable to replace the digits

```
para = "support leaders around the world who do not speak for the big 
polluters, but who speak for all of humanity, for the indigenous people of 
the world, for the first 100 people.In 90's it seems true."

import re
import nltk

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(para)

for i in range(len(sentences)):
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentences[i])
    words = [re.sub(r'\d','',words)]
    sentences[i] = ' '.join(words)
```

while doing this i am getting following error:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-000671b45ee1> in <module>()
       2 for i in range(len(sentences)):
       3     words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentences[i])
 ----> 4     words = [re.sub(r'\d','',words)].encode('utf8')
       5     sentences[i] = ' '.join(words)

~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
  189     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
  190     a replacement string to be used."""
  --> 191     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  192 
  193  def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How can i convert to byte like object. I am confused as i am new to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For replacing all digits from a string, you can the `re` module, for matching and replacing regex patterns. From your last example:

```
import re

processed_words = [re.sub('\d',' ', word) for word in tokenized]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is trying to tell you that you called `re.sub` with something that is not a string (ignore the "or bytes" and the "-like" parts: you have real strings to work with). The culprit is `words`: The function `nltk.word_tokenize()` returns a list, and you cannot pass the whole thing to `re.sub`. You need another for-loop, or a comprehension. Here it is with a comprehension, applying `re.sub` to each element `w` of `words`.

```
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(para)
for i in range(len(sentences)):
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentences[i])
    words = [re.sub(r'\d','',w) for w in words]
    sentences[i] = ' '.join(words)
```

While we're at it, I recommend replacing your loop over numbers with a loop over the list elements. Much nicer this way, but you must store the results in a new list:

```
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(para)
clean = []
for sent in sentences:
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
    words = [re.sub(r'\d','',w) for w in words]
    clean.append(' '.join(words))
```

PS. You could simplify your code by applying the replacement to whole sentences, or even to the entire paragraph before you split it. But that's not relevant to your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do? Or am I missing the point?

```
import re

para = """support leaders around the world who do not speak for the big 
polluters, but who speak for all of humanity, for the indigenous people of 
the world, for the first 100 people.In 90's it seems true."""

tokenized = para.split(' ')
new_para = []
for w in tokenized:
    w = re.sub('[0-9]', '', w)
    new_para.append(w)
print(' '.join(new_para))
```